# How to add a class on an option tag that belongs to a select tag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I am trying to add a class to the option tag generated by the following code:

```
=f.datetime_select :clock_out, {class: 'option-large'}
```

I am not sure how to get this to work. Does this helper provide a way to assign a class to the option tags generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) ? You need to generate yourself the options as well but you can set html attributes too.

So it would be something like

```
select_options = options.map do |option|
                   [option.display_value,   # <option>this</option>
                    option.value,           # <option value="this"></option>
                    option.html_attributes] # a hash here <option class="option"></option>
                 end
=f.datetime_select :clock_out,
                   options_for_select(select_options,
                                      :selected => _your_default_value_)
                   {class: 'option-large'}
```

You could otherwise add a class using Ruby/Javascript once the HTML code is generated.
In Ruby (server side), you could store the result of datetime_select and gsub it.
In Javascript (client side), you select your options and add class to the one you want.

Comment: I will use Javascript. I was hoping there was a cleaner solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from ruby api:

```
datetime_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

so:

html_options = {:class => "option-large"}

Comment: try this: 

f.datetime_select :clock_out,nil ,nil, html_options = {class: 'option-large'}

Comment: that doesn't work either. Wrong number of arguments error. If i take one nil out it still doesn't work...

Comment: try : f.datetime_select :clock_out, "try", html_options = {class: 'option-large'}

Comment: sorry: f.datetime_select :clock_out, "try", :html_options => {class: 'option-large'}